# How to insert foreign key value in Child table in c#

Tags: c#, insert, foreign-keys

i am trying to fill a foreign key value in child table with using parametric insert query
statically i get success but when i am trying to do it dynamically it does not work

my parent table is `Customer`
custId(pk),CustName,contact are the fields there

and child table is `_order`
orderId(pk),item,qauntity,cust_Id(fk) are filelds

my code for insertion in c# is:

```
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer (custname,contact)values(@custname,@contact)", conn);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname", cusname.Text);
                scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact.Text);
                scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into  _order (item,qauntity,cust_Id) select @item,@qauntity,custId from Customer where custId= @custId", conn);
                scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item.Text);
                scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qauntity", qauntity.Text);
                scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

when i give a hard code value in second query on where condition it works but how to do it dynamically 
i think everyone understand my problem please help
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Customer (custname,contact)values(@custname,@contact); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", conn);
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname", cusname.Text);
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact.Text);
int custId = Convert.ToInt32(scmd.ExecuteScalar());

SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into  _order (item,qauntity,cust_Id) VALUES(@item,@qauntity,@custId)", conn);
scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", item.Text);
scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qauntity", qauntity.Text);
scmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custId", custId);
scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: wow great  it is working but please tell me what i was doing wrong in my code which recover in this new code.....and why the ExecuteScaler replaced by ExecuteNonQuery..please Elaborate i am new with c#